# How to use form sections from separate file?

Tags: swiftui, ios14

Earlier this year I created an app using SwiftUI. One part of this app is broken when running in iOS 14. I have a creation and editing form, the goal is to reuse the sections that they have in common. Previously it worked to have these sections in a `Group`, since iOS 14 that fails and puts all sections into a single view.

It's currently implemented similar to this:

```swift
struct CreateForm: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Text("First section")
            }
            OtherSections()
        }
    }
}

struct OtherSections: View {
    var body: some View {
        Group { // <--- This is causing the issue
            Section {
                Text("First Detail Section")
            }

            // In real implementation there are some conditional sections
            if false {
                Section {
                    Text("Second Detail Section")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `@ViewBuilder` instead of `Group`:

```
struct OtherSections: View {
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Text("First Detail Section")
        }

        // In real implementation there are some conditional sections
        if false {
            Section {
                Text("Second Detail Section")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Also make sure `OtherSections` conforms to `View`)

Comment: Okay, bit annoyed I couldn't find that. I kinda expected something like that but couldn't find it. `OtherSections` did already conform to `View` in actual implementation.